# Nginx $arg_name variable is empty when URL is not root

Tags: nginx

I am trying set cookie for users based on specific query strings that might exist in the request.

I was able to set up a `map` block so that if such parameter exists, it would generate the cookie value, which is then used with an `add_header` directive. However, I realized that `Set-cookie` headers are not being sent on 404. I added a `/test` route which returns 200 response, but still no sign of Set-Cookie header.

I then created a log format to only include that $arg_name variable, which is when I noticed the variable is populated only if the URL matches the root. Here is the sample I was working on. I am using **Nginx 1.15.7**.

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '"$arg_foo"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    map $arg_foo $foo_cookie {
        "~*[a-z0-9\-\_]" "foo=$arg_foo; Domain=$host; Max-Age=14400; httponly";
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        add_header Set-Cookie $foo_cookie;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location /test {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location / {
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    }
}
```

When the request is `localhost:80/?foo=bar`, the logs show `"bar"` and the `Set-Cookie` header is sent.
When the request is `localhost:80/test?foo=bar`, the logs show `"-"` which means the variable is empty, and as result, `Set-Cookie` header is **not** sent!

I even removed the `map` statement and `add_header` directive, but the result in the logs are the same, which confirms that the problem is somewhere else. What am I missing here?

Comment: `add_header` needs `always` (for v1.7.5+) in order to work for all response codes (400s and stuff): http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

Comment: I found setting nginx `error_log` level to `debug` very useful in debugging directives involving variables (custom or not).

Comment: If the `try_files` in `location /test` takes the default action of `/index.html`, the arguments have been removed. Maybe you should use `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;`

Comment: @AliSattari, thanks for the pointer about the always flag. That fixed the 404 issue.

Comment: @RichardSmith, that seems to fix the issue for the `/test` path! Thanks! It was my understanding that these variables are evaluated globaly, not per action! Do you know a better way to handle this regardless of the location? I want all of the requests to be processed, regardless of location blocks and how they are served. I want this to be the top level rule.